# How to use plugin jquery.dropdown.js in xslt

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, model-view-controller, xhtml

I am using jquery.dropdown.js plugin. my page is built on xslt. Tell me what are the features in the construction.
How to use this plugn?
`disabled selected` - not working.
Error - Missing attribute value on attribute 'disabled'.
Error - Missing attribute value on attribute 'selected'.

```
 <div class="demo">
<select style="display:none"  name="tstate_next_ttype11" multiple ="multiple">
    <option value=" " disabled selected></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="3" >Selected</option>
    <option value="4" >Disabled</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    
  </select>
 </div>
```

JS

```
$('.demo').dropdown({
        readOnly: false,
        limitCount: Infinity,
        multipleMode: 'label',
        input: '<input type="text" maxLength="20" placeholder="Search">',
        searchable: true,
        searchNoData: '<li style="color:#ddd">No Results</li>',
        choice: function () { }
    });
```

Comment: In XML (and XSLT), attributes must have a value. As a default, the value can equal the name, for example `<option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>`.

Comment: And that value can also be empty like otherattribute=“”